# El tipo "number" no tiene propiedades en común con el tipo "Stock"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Estoy creando una función para eliminar campos de una base de datos mostrados en una tabla mediante una petición post, pero al mandar el parámetro con el id para el header da el siguiente error:

El tipo "number" no tiene propiedades en común con el tipo "Stock"

El codigo que hay en el ts es el siguiente:

```
export class StockPage implements OnInit {

  stock: Stock[]
  
  selected = 0;

  constructor(private stockCtrl:StockService) {
    this.stockCtrl.cargaStock().subscribe(resp => {
      this.stock = resp['stock'];
      console.log(this.stock);})
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onClick( item: any ) {
    console.log(item);
    this.selected = item.idstock
  }

  borrar() {
    console.log(this.selected);
    
    this.stockCtrl.borrarStock(this.selected)
  }
}
```

En el servicio tengo las funciones para cargar, crear, modificar y borrar los datos de la base de datos, la función de borrar está así:

```
borrarStock(post:Stock) {
    this.token = this.usuarioCtrl.token;
            
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'x-token':this.token
    });

    headers.append('x-token',this.token);
    headers.append('x-iddelete',post.idstock.toString())
    console.log(headers);

    return this.http.post(`${URL}/api/stock/delete`,post,{headers});
  }
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiera dar una solución al error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad `selected` de `StockPage` es del tipo `number` y estas pasando el valor de esta propiedad como argumento de la llamada a `borrarStock`

```
export class StockPage implements OnInit {
  ...

  selected = 0; // <- esta propiedad es del tipo number

  ...

  borrar() {
    ...
    
    this.stockCtrl.borrarStock(this.selected) // <- estas pasando un number como argumento
  }
}
```

Sin embargo en el `StockService` tienes definido el parámetro `post` del método `borrarStock` como del tipo `Stock`

```
borrarStock(post:Stock) { // <-- espera un Stock
  ...
}
```

---

Como los tipos no concuerdan te está dando ese error.
Para solucionarlo, tendrás que:

- o bien guardar en `selected` el `Stock` seleccionado al completo.
- o sino definir el parámetro post de borrarStock como number. `borrarStock(post:number)`

Elige la solución que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades.

un saludo